# Less memory then process used still does not close the process

Tags: powershell, memory, command-line

I want to close a specific process if the memory specified is lower than mentioned in the script. The memory Used in Resource Monitor and Task Manager is specified in K, which I assume is Kilobytes. In my script I specify the memory in KB, which I obtained from working memory in Resource Monitor, but still my process does not close.

The basic idea of the script is to close the process if memory used is less than specified and the Internet is working. If both conditions are met then close the process. But my process does not close. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

```
sleep -s 60
while ($true) {
    Get-Process calc -ea 0 | where { $_.PM -le 488300KB } | foreach {
        $Path = $_.Path
        [bool]$Ping = Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Quiet
        if ($Path -and $Ping) {
            Stop-Process $_ -Force
            Start-Process $Path
        }
    } 
    sleep -s 30
}
```

Comment: While the default `Get-Process` output displays memory sizes in KB the actual values of the memory-related properties are in Bytes. Also, `PM` is the the paged memory size, i.e. the portion of the process' memory that is swapped to disk. If you want the portion that is in the physical memory you need `WS` (the working set). For the total process memory (physical and paged) use `VM` (the virtual memory size).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers What do u mean sir,what memory should i write in script VM or WS.And what is VM is it the commit in Resource Monitor.THANKU.

Comment: @Amreign The primary process memory indicator in Task Manager (the "active private working set") reflects the `\Process\Working Set Private` performance counter, you'll want to retrieve that